# mounting partition images made with dd

Tags: mount, dd, disk-image

is there a way to mount and access a single partition on any mountpoint in my filesystem or must I use disk images and mount with offset?

I made a partiton image with `dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdb1 of=~/part.img` and tried to mount it on /mnt with `mount -t vfat ~/part.img /mnt`.

The output of mount is an Unknown Error -1

Comment: That *should* work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to mount partition images made with dd.  You should add a `-o loop` (i.e., use a loopback device) to the mount command.

The final command should look like:
`mount -oloop -t vfat ~/part.img /mnt`

Of course, you should have dd'ed from a valid and previously formatted vfat filesystem in the original partition.

Comment: +1 I've found that using `-o loop` is generally not necessary; `man mount` notes "The mount command **automatically creates a loop device from a regular file** if a filesystem type  is  not  specified  or  the filesystem is known for libblkid..." -- but the last part is a bit of a qualifier, hopefully using `-t vfat ` and `-o loop` together works.

Comment: @Marcelo I tried the mounting procedure again with `mount -t vfat -o loop ~/part.img /mnt` and it works perfectly today. Now it seems I cannot reproduce the weird error. But many thanks anyway.

Comment: @IlikePepsi, do you mean you cannot reproduce the error even when not specifying `-o loop` as you did the first time?  That's weird indeed.  Well, good that now it works.

Comment: @Marcelo, yes. I thought that maybe the created loop device persists somehow but it doesn't. I tried `losetup -l` and the loop-device was gone after `umount /mnt`